# Installing npm package acs fails due to incompatibility with tar@0.1.13

Tags: installation, npm, command-line-interface, tar, acs

I'm trying to install the package acs through npm, but it fails and says it's not compatible with tar@0.1.13.

However when I run npm -g list it says that my installed version of tar is 2.1.1.

```
➜  ~  npm info tar version
2.1.1
```

But when I try to install acs it fails due to incompatibility with tar. See logs below:

```
➜  ~  npm install -g acs@1.0.25

> ws@0.4.32 install       
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/acs/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "acs@1.0.25"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.1
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: tar@0.1.13
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"~0.5.9 || 0.6 || 0.7 || 0.8"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.13.1","node":"0.12.7"}

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sinkensabe/npm-debug.log
```

I cant figure out why it says that it is incompatible with tar@0.1.13 when this is not a version that seems to be installed on my unix system.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, not sure why though.. Removed everything related to node and installed node with homebrew. Then installing acs worked without any problems.

Followed the instructions here to remove node: http://tinyurl.com/qxyax6y